# check element has value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

how to get the value of an element in xslt. suppose my xml like this,

```
<comp>
 <link ref=1>1997</link>
 <link ref=2><?LINK 2008?></link>
</comp>
```

i need output like this,

```
<comp>
  <link ssref=1/><num>1997</num>
  <link ssref=2/><num>2008</num>
</comp>
```

if the link has value i need to get that value, if it has like this `<?LINK 2008?>` i just need year from that. i used following xsl but it's not working.

```
<xsl:template match ="link">
<xsl:element name ="{local-name(.)}">
  <xsl:attribute name ="sshref">
    <xsl:value-of select ="@ref"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
<xsl:if test="text()">
  <xsl:element name ="num">
    <xsl:value-of select ="link"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
</template>
```

i know this xsl wrong i just posted for some reference.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your XML isn't well-formed, as attributes should be enclosed in apostrophes or quotes, but I am guessing that may be a simple typo.

As for the specific issue  is a processing-instruction, and so your **xsl:if** that checks for text() will not pick this up.

You've also got an issue where you do `<xsl:value-of select="link" />` because your current context is already on the **link** element, and so this is looking for another **link** element that is the child of the current one. You probably just want want to do something like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

So, you could re-write your template like so

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:attribute name="sshref">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ref"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="text()|processing-instruction()">
            <xsl:element name="num">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|processing-instruction()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, it is worth noting it is often better to avoid the use of **xsl:if** elements, and use the power of template matching instead. Try this alternate XSLT instead.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="link[text()|processing-instruction()]">
      <link>
         <num>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|processing-instruction()"/>
         </num>
      </link>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="link/@ref">
      <xsl:attribute name="ssref">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::processing-instruction())]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XMK

```
<comp>
   <link ref="1">1997</link>
   <link ref="2"><?LINK 2008?></link>
</comp>
```

The following is output:

```
<comp>
   <link sshref="1">
      <num>1997</num>
   </link>
   <link sshref="2">
      <num>2008</num>
   </link>
</comp>
```

Do note there is no need to use **xsl:element** unless you want a dynamically named element.

Comment: +1, though your XSLT can be simplified a bit more. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest XSLT transformation you could do looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="link/text() | link/processing-instruction()">
    <num><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" /></num>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="link/@ref">
     <xsl:attribute name="ssref"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<comp>
 <link ref="1">1997</link>
 <link ref="2"><?LINK 2008?></link>
</comp>
```

into the desired result.

```
<comp>
 <link ssref="1"><num>1997</num></link>
 <link ssref="2"><num>2008</num></link>
</comp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not well formatted, it should be like this:

```xml
<comp>
  <link ref="1">1997</link>
  <link ref="2"><?LINK 2008?></link>
</comp>
```

and then you can use the following XSLT to get your desired result:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="comp">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comp/link">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:attribute name="sshref"><xsl:value-of select="@ref"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="text()|processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:element name="num">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|processing-instruction()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```